# Spring WebFlux, extracting the request body

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, reactive

I am writing a small WebFlux client proxy that will accept a POST request, extract the JSON content, and pass that on to a further call to a third party web server via another POST.  I want to get a hold of the json body in my original POST request.

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"username":"xyz", "preference":"123"}' \
  http://localhost:3000/mih/search
```

Here is my route to handle the above POST:

```
@Bean
open fun route(searchService: SearchService): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> {
    return RouterFunctions.route(
            RequestPredicates.POST("/search").and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)),
            HandlerFunction {
                    request: ServerRequest -> searchService.search(request.body(BodyExtractors.toMono(String::class.java)))
            } )
    }
```

```
open class SearchService(private val myWebClient: MyWebClient): ISearchService {

    override fun search(json: String): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        return myWebClient.myPost(json)
    }
}
```

```
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient

open class MyWebClient(
    private val springWebClient: WebClient,
    private val properties: properties ) : IMyWebClient {

    override fun myPost(json: String): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        return springWebClient.post()
            .uri("/{base}/queries", properties.getBase)
            .body(
                BodyInserters.fromPublisher(Mono.just(json), String::class.java)
            ).retrieve().bodyToMono(
                ServerResponse::class.java
            )
    }
}
```

When I go to `.subscribe()` to the `Mono<String>` I get

```
Type mismatch.
  Required: String
  Found: Disposable
```

How do I successfully extract the body of the request?

Comment: `WebClient.post(json)` i have not seen that function before, and i can't find it in the api declaration. You need to call `exchange` or `retreive` to perform the request, then take the response and extract and map the body to something. You can read more about the usages of WebClient in the official documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-retrieve

Comment: @MeanwhileInHell - I think that you should call `bodyToMono<String>` on your webClient and then wrap string into new object of `ServerResponse`

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html#post--

`post()` returns `WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec` and not `ServerResponse`

Your usage of API is incorrect. You should use `.retrieve()` after the `search()` method call.

In your case `.body()` is applied to POST request body.

You should proceed with:

`.search().retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class)`

Comment: Apologies, my question should have been more concise.  I am calling `retreive()` from the call from WebClient.  I have edited my answer to include my own web clients code and extended background information.

Comment: Still, you can't call `.bodyToMono(ServerResponse::class.java)` and expect that it automagically turn into response, what you can do is to call `bodyToMono<String>()` and then `map` to return `ServerResponse`. Reactor does not know how to map some kind of string into `ServerResponse` nor it knows which status code to return...